# Python overlapping sliding dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm implementing a machine learning algorithm and I'm extracting features out of a dataframe. I obviously need overlapping windows. Suppose the DataFrame looks like this

```
 x     y   z
 12.1  11  0.5
 12.2  10  0.3
 12.4  11  0.5
 12.8  12  0.4
 13.1  13  0.4
 14.7  14  0.5
 15.2  14  0.6
 15.3  13  0.5
 17.3  14  0.5
 18.2  15  0.4
 16.1  16  0.2
 15.0  17  0.1
```

But in reality a lot larger (thousands of samples). I now want a list of dataframes where each `DataFrame` is of length `ws` (here 150) and to have `step` (stride) of 60.

This is what I got

```
r = np.arange(len(df))
s = r[::step]
return [df.iloc[k:k+ws] for k in s]
```

This works reasonably good but there's still one problem. The last 1,2 or 3 frames might not have length `ws`. I also cannot just discard the last 3 since there's sometimes only one with a length smaller then `ws`. So the `s` variable just keeps all the start indices, I'd need a way to have only the start indices where `start_index + step < len(df)`. Unless of course, there are better and or faster ways for this (maybe a library). All existing documentation only talks about simple arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might only need to change `s`:

```
s = r[:len(df)-ws+1:step]
```

In this way you only find the start indexes of frames with length `ws`.

Comment: Thanks! I now added an extra line `s = list(filter(lambda x: x+ws <= len(df), s))` but your solution is more elegant